# Do I need to learn probability for CLRS?

Tags: algorithm-analysis

I am currently learning Discrete mathematics.

there is a topic on dicrete probability (which I havent covered yet), but I also know there is non-discrete probabiltiy but I dont know what they really are.

My aim is to learn math so I can understand CLRS, is probability needed for clrs ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're studying CS at school, I'd recommend just learning what the curriculum tells you to. CLRS is intro to algorithms, which is a pretty broad subject. Do you technically need any prereqs? Not really, but will it benefit you eventually? Yes. It might take a while, but off the top of my head, there are some continuous probability concepts that appear later on when you need to prove algorithms with randomization and prove that it works with high probability. In these cases, you might not always have a discrete probability system.

In terms of discrete vs non-discrete probability, it's not so much about learning one or the other. They are sort of related in terms of concepts (fundamentally it's pretty much the same), but because of finite elements vs infinite elements, the math checks out differently.

At the end of the day, probability is just

$$\frac{\text{what you want}}{\text{what you want} + \text{what you don't want}}$$

These values might represent a discrete set, or a continuous set (geometric), but the concept is still the same.

So TLDR I would recommend learning everything, as it will definitely be useful down the line, but for practical reasons, just follow whatever your curriculum tells you to do.

It never hurts to learn more.